# Bxslider - show images as they load

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I am using a Bxslider on my site and the markup goes like this:

```
<div class="slide"> 
<a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="image.jpg"/></a> 
</div>
<div class="slide"> 
<a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="image2.jpg"/></a> 
</div>
<div class="slide"> 
<a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="image3.jpg"/></a> 
</div>
<div class="slide"> 
<a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="image4.jpg"/></a> 
</div>
<div class="slide"> 
<a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="image5.jpg"/></a> 
</div>
```

Since some images used are too big, slider is taking long time to load.While loading, its displaying rotating circle and only shows images when ALL of them are loaded.
Is there any chance that i can force it to show images as they load, one at a time?

This is jQuery that makes it work:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.slider1').bxSlider({
            slideWidth: 258,
            minSlides: 1,
            maxSlides: 3.5,
            slideMargin: 10,
          });
        });
```

Comment: preloadImages:

did you try this

Comment: If you mean like this, then yea, no luck :\
  $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.slider1').bxSlider({
            slideWidth: 258,
            minSlides: 1,
            maxSlides: 3.5,
            slideMargin: 10,
           preloadImages: 'all',
          });
        });

Answer (score 0):

**Try this trick**

In starting put **display:none** css to your div that contains all your slides

```
<div class="slide" style="display:none">
```

And use this JS code

```
var obj;
$(document).ready(function(){
    obj=$('.slide').bxSlider({
       slideWidth: 258,
       minSlides: 1,
       maxSlides: 3.5,
       slideMargin: 10,
    });
   $(".slide").show();
   obj.reloadSlider(); 
});
```

Where the reloadSlider() is bx-slider lib inbuilt function.

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you Deepak, but im afraid it isnt working, now its just loading forever :\
Maybe i did something wrong? http://webnroll.info/lustre/, if you have a time to throw a look :)

Comment: And also there is a JS error coming on your page "TypeError: $(...).uniform is not a function" due to given js code file i.e http://www.lustrelife.com/js/js_func.js line no. 9 , try to fix that

Comment: Thank you, it works now, but it is still waiting for all images to load before showing them.But thank you either way :)

I dont have access to that JS file, and even if i did, it must stay like that for some unknown reasons -.-

Comment: have you checked this by removing the obj.reloadSlider();  line from js code?

Comment: Yes, i did it like you advised (its live on above link) and still nothing